# em-websocket send() send from one client to another through 2 servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, em-websocket

I have two websocket clients, and I want to exchange information between them.

Let's say I have two instances of socket servers, and 1st is retrieve private information, filter it and send to the second one.

```
require 'em-websocket'

EM.run do
  EM::WebSocket.run(host: '0.0.0.0', port: 19108) do |manager_emulator|
    # retrieve information. After that I need to send it to another port (9108)
  end

  EM::WebSocket.run(host: '0.0.0.0', port: 9108) do |fake_manager|
    # I need to send filtered information here
  end
end
```

I've tried to do something, but I got usual dark code and I don't know how to implement this functionality.

Comment: why are you raising an exception in the middle of defining your services? (`raise manager_emulator.inspect`)

Comment: omg, I used this for debugging. I'll remove it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way how to do it through `em-websocket` gem! You need just define variables outside of eventmachine block. Something like that

```
require 'em-websocket'

message_sender = nil

EM.run do
  # message sender
  EM::WebSocket.run(host: '0.0.0.0', port: 19108) do |ws|
    ws.onopen { message_sender = ws }
    ws.onclose { message_sender = nil }
  end

  # message receiver
  EM::WebSocket.run(host: '0.0.0.0', port: 9108) do |ws|
    ws.onmessage { |msg| message_sender.send(msg) if message_sender }
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice workaround. But it seems to me that if Event Machine is multi-threading (which it probably shouldn't) or cycling through asynchronous events (which I think it does), you are running a risk of data corruption and clashes when you have multiple clients.... But I might be wrong. EM was meant to circumvent some of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would do that using EM.

I'm assuming you will need to have the fake_manager listen to an event triggered by the manager_emulator.

It would be quite easy if you'd be using a websocket web-app framework. For instance, on the [Plezi web-app framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) you could write something like this:

```
# try the example from your terminal.
# use http://www.websocket.org/echo.html in two different browsers to observe:
#
# Window 1: http://localhost:3000/manager
# Window 2: http://localhost:3000/fake

require 'plezi'

class Manager_Controller
    def on_message data
        FakeManager_Controller.broadcast :_send, "Hi, fake! Please do something with: #{data}\r\n- from Manager."
        true
    end
    def _send message
        response << message
    end
end
class FakeManager_Controller
    def on_message data
        Manager_Controller.broadcast :_send, "Hi, manager! This is yours: #{data}\r\n- from Fake."
        true
    end
    def _send message
        response << message
    end
end
class HomeController
    def index
        "use http://www.websocket.org/echo.html in two different browsers to observe this demo in action:\r\n" +
        "Window 1: http://localhost:3000/manager\r\nWindow 2: http://localhost:3000/fake\r\n"
    end
end

# # optional Redis URL: automatic broadcasting across processes or machines:
# ENV['PL_REDIS_URL'] = "redis://username:password@my.host:6379"

# starts listening with default settings, on port 3000
listen

# Setup routes:
# They are automatically converted to the RESTful route: '/path/(:id)'
route '/manager', Manager_Controller
route '/fake', FakeManager_Controller
route '/', HomeController

# exit terminal to start server
exit
```

Good Luck!

P.S.

If you're going to keep to EM, you might consider using Redis to push and subscribe to events between the two ports.

Comment: Thanks for help! I've found a way how I can implement it using eventmachine. Please check the answer